# Escape MongoDB regex character in Spring SpEL - getting SpelParseException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-el

I'm trying to override the MongoRepository::findAll() method to define the custom `@Query`. I am following the [SpEL JPA Query support docs](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) to have similar logic in MongoRepository to check for user role and create a dynamic query to fetch the authorized records.

I've the following method setup in my BlogRepository which extends MongoRepository:

```
@Query("{ user_id : ?#{ hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ?  /./  : principal.userId } } ")
@Override
Page<Blog> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

I get the following error from this method:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1049E:(pos 31): Unexpected data after '.': 'div(/)'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.raiseInternalException(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:988)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatDottedNode(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:407)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.maybeEatNode(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:360)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatPrimaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:345)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatUnaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:337)
```

---

As the below mongo query runs and retuns the desired values, I believe, I just need to escape the `/./` character so that SpEL doesn't try to parse it.

```
    { 'user_id' : /./ }
```

I couldn't find a escape character for SpEL but played with the following options and still similar kind of parse exception is coming up:

- `'/./'`
- `#{/./}`     -- wraping with SpEL expression
- `.`
- `/.*.*/`

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working :

```
@Query("  ?#{ hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? '{}' : {'user_id' :  principal.userId } } ")
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you can use escape function like

```
%?#{escape(...)}
```